# AVPlayer not playing streaming radio with dynamic URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

AVPlayer on iOS is perfectly playing radio when doing this

```
AVPlayer *player;
player =[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kantipur-stream.softnep.com:7248"]];

[player play]
```

But it doesn't play any radio when I use NSString variable called link to hold url string of different radios like

```
AVPlayer *player;
player =[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];

[player play]
```

link is fetched and parsed from an XML document.
I can't understand whats the problem.

Comment: Print link value ... make sure link has desired URL ...

Comment: I did that and its printing desired URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code....its working good for me...

```
NSString *string=@"http://kantipur-stream.softnep.com:7248";
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayer.view.hidden = YES;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

and don't forget to add a media playerFramework

or
url encoding

```
-(NSString *)urlencode:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *encodeString=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return encodeString;
}
```

and your code

```
NSString *string=@"http://kantipur-stream.softnep.com:7248";
player =[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self urlencode:string]]];

[player play];
```

Comment: and again it doesn't work when I provide url dynamically. As I said link is obtained dynamically from XML file that lives on web. When I print the value it shows correctly but doesn't stream.

Comment: its working good for me too when I directly provide the url in code. Problem seems to be in the url received from xml. While it shows exactly desired when printing there must be some formatting/encoding issue.

Comment: Thanks karthikeyan. And it works. Objective c is really weird. Can you describe why thats required when saving in NSString variable?

Comment: refer this link it will more helpful to you  http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios         you can up vote for me.